# Python Spark: Java out of memory error

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am facing a problem while I am trying to load a tif file with the help from spark. It gives me the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

```
import thunder as td
sc = SparkContext("local","app1")
img = td.images.fromtif('20160511_HuC_H2B_G6s_F1_00002.tif','tif',None,None,False,None,None,None,sc,None).npartitions(100)
```

1- I tried to update "spark-env.sh" and "spark-defaults.conf" with

> spark.executor.memory 2000m

2- I tried to make it like this :

```
sc = SparkContext("local","app1","--executor-memory 20G")
```

3- I tried to add a config variable

(Updated)

```
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.executor.memory", "2000m")
sc = SparkContext("local","simple app", conf = conf)
```

4- I added to bash file:

> export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms512m -Xmx4g"

I got the same error every time, I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. first I downloaded the source code of spark then I built it again with sbt, after than i created spark-env.sh in conf file with the following:

```
SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES=14
SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=4G
SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=4G
```

I tried the pre-built version of spark with this before but it did not work.